# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}-(x^{α+1})^q}{(x-x^q)x^{αc}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the function:
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\frac{x-x^q}{1-q}, \quad 0<q<1
\end{equation}
I would like to prove that the function defined as:
\begin{equation}
h_c(α)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x^{α+1})}{g(x)x^{αc}}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c=q$, is equal to $1$.
In other words I wanna prove that the limit:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}-(x^{α+1})^q}{(x-x^q)x^{αc}}=1
\end{equation}

But I am not able to see how would I prove that. I have given it some tries but I do not end up with a result.
Thanks!

***Update.***

I have been studying a paper on $q$-Generalized Entropies and therefore there are numerous limits like this one which are tricky. Taking into account the responses below and also the author of the paper who claims that the limit has to be equal to $1$ I was in doubt, whether that could be correct or not. So, for $c=q$ my approach was the following:

\begin{align}
h_c(α)& = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x^{α+1})}{g(x)x^{αq}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}-(x^{α+1})^q}{(x-x^q)x^{αq}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}-x^{αq+q}}{(x-x^q)x^{αq}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{x^{α+1}}{(x-x^q)x^{αq}}-\frac{x^{αq}x^q}{(x-x^q)x^{αq}}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}}{(x-x^q)x^{αq}}-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^q}{(x-x^q)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}}{(x-x^q)x^{αq}}+\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^q}{x^q(1-x^{1-q})}=A+B
\end{align}

The $A$ limit would be:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}}{(x-x^q)x^{αq}}&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α}x}{x(1-x^{q-1})x^{αq}}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α}}{(1-x^{q-1})x^{αq}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α(1-q)}}{1-x^{q-1}}=α(1-q)\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α(1-q)-1}}{-(q-1)x^{q-2}}\\
&=α \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{α(1-q)-1}}{x^{q-2}}=α \lim_{x \to 0}x^{α(1-q)-1+2-q}\\
&=α \lim_{x \to 0}x^{(α+1)-q(α+1)}=α\lim_{x \to 0}x^{(α+1)(1-q)}=0
\end{align}
since $q<1 \Leftrightarrow 1-q>0$. The second limit is easy to find that it is equal to $1$. Therefore $A+B=0+1=1=h_c(α), \forall q \in (0,1), α+1>0 \Leftrightarrow α>-1$.
Is that correct or wrong? If it is wrong, please point it out to me, I really would like to understand why. Moreover, I cannot explain the contradiction with the $c=q=1/2$ case. How could it be? Perhaps due to $α=-3$?

Comment: My answer shows that the conditions are q=c and a>-1.

Comment: @martycohen Yeap, I can see that and it is obviously clear that you are right. But what happens if I am not in position to know that my limit should be equal to $1$. I mean, now I could see it and I was already able to know that the answer is $1$. I am just trying to figure out the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the conditions
so that
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{α+1}-(x^{α+1})^q}{(x-x^q)x^{αc}}=1
$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x^{a+1}-(x^{a+1})^q}{(x-x^q)x^{ac}}
&=\dfrac{x^{q(a+1)}(x^{(1-q)(a+1)}-1)}{x^{q+ac}(x^{1-q}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{x^{qa+q-q-ac}(1-x^{(1-q)(a+1)})}{1-x^{1-q}}\\
&=\dfrac{x^{qa-ac}(1-x^{(1-q)(a+1)})}{1-x^{1-q}}\\
&=\dfrac{x^{a(q-c)}(1-x^{(1-q)(a+1)})}{1-x^{1-q}}\\
\end{array}
$

Since $0 < q < 1$,
$x^{1-q} \to 0$.

For the numerator to $\to 1$,
we must have
$q = c$
and
$(1-q)(a+1) > 0$
or
$a > -1$.

It looks like
these are the conditions you need.

Answer (score 1):

It does not hold. Take $\alpha=-3$, $q=1/2$ and $c=1/2$. Your limit becomes

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{-2}-(x^{-2})^{1/2}}{(x-\sqrt{x})x^{-3/2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1/x^{2}-1/|x|}{(x-\sqrt{x})x^{-3/2}}=-\infty\ .
\end{equation}

Comment: But could it be that it does not hold? I see that you have chosen $c=q$. That would be something I did not mention, the true case is that $c=q$. I have to check if I have provided any wrong information, but it has to be equal to $1$.

Comment: @Mitscaype Sorry, I don't get what you are saying. I chose $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c$ and $q$ between $0$ and $1$, as per your post. *By chance* I picked $c=q$. You are now saying that $c$ *should be indeed* equal to $q$. And I showed to you that your limit is *not* 1 *in general*. Might it be $=1$ for some *specific* choices of $\alpha$ and $c=q$? Maybe...but what else exactly do you need?

Comment: Yes, my English was trully bad above, I can see now :/ Well I was in a hurry since I really was struggling to figure out how could it be possible that it does not hold. I did not explain properly what I meant, but I made and edit to the main post, I hope it is clear now.